# Порядок преобразования типов аргументов в сложном выражении, C/C++

Tags: c, cast

Не совсем уверен, что происходит в следующем случае:

```
const char c = ...;
const int i = ...;
const float f = ...;

const int r = c + i + f;
```

Мне известны правила, согласно которым `char` в любых операциях продвигается до `int` или `unsigned int`, в зависимости от особенностей размеров. Мне так же известно, что оба операнда оператора перед операцией преобразуются к типу, наиболее старшему из двух:

```
char -> unsigned char -> short -> unsigned short -> ...
```

Но я не совсем понимаю, как все это происходит в сложном выражении.

Строго по очереди и локально?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В С фактически нет "сложных выражений". Все операторы в С являются либо унарными, либо бинарными (за исключением `?:`). Рассмотрение всегда ведется в рамках одного оператора, т.е. сводится к рассмотрению максимум *двух* операндов.

В выражении `c + i + f` группировка операторов и операндов имеет вид `(c + i) + f`.

Поэтому отдельно рассматривается подвыражение `c + i`. Это выражение вида `char + int`. В рамках *usual arithmetic conversions* первый операнд подвергается *integral promotions* и преобразуется к типу `int` (или `unsigned int`, как вы сами заметили, но отнесем этот вариант к разряду экзотических). После этого типы обоих операндов совпадают. Результат `R` имеет тип `int`.

Затем рассматривается подвыражение `R + f`, которое имеет вид `int + float`. Здесь тоже работают *usual arithmetic conversions* и первый операнд преобразуется к типу `float`. Результат имеет тип `float`.

---

> Мне так же известно, что оба операнда оператора перед операцией преобразуются к типу, наиболее старшему из двух

Даже если ограничиться рассмотрением только арифметических типов, то такое "сведение" типов делается не во всех бинарных операциях. В операторах побитового сдвига, например, выполняются лишь *integral promotions*, а не все *usual arithmetic conversions*. Тип результата сдвига - это тип именно *первого* операнда (после *integral promotions*).

```
char a = 1;
unsigned long long b = 1;

a + b;  // тип `unsigned long long`
a << b; // тип `int`
```